# Pass type as parameter to newtonsoft json deserialize

Tags: json, vb.net

I have this working line of code

```
Public Shared Function JSONArrayToObject(source As String, result As Type) As Object
    Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of PAManufacturer())(source)
End Function
```

result is a type and I would like to replace PAManufacturer with GetType(result) or the equivalent.

I haven't been able to get around this problem.  I could have a hundred of these deserialize methods but i'm sure I should be able to use the result variable somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic functions (of which `DeserializeObject` is one) for this:

```
Public Shared Function JSONArrayToObject(Of T)(source As String) As T()
    Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T())(source)
End Function
```

Where you could call it as:

```
Dim arr as PAManufacturer() = JSONArrayToObject(Of PAManufacturer())(someSourceString)
```

Though if you get to that level, one wonders why you use a function at all, and not just have the code call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` directly.

Comment: You've done me proud thanks,  I removed other bits of code that log various items in that method, that's the only reason the code is not used directly as per your second suggestion.  Thank you for your help

Comment: @user174634 I figured there might be more to it than what you were presenting, glad it helped!